# Unable to Install Intel Network Driver

Tags: windows, networking, drivers, ssd

Brand new HP Prodesk 600 G3. Swapped internal hard drive to SSD. Windows 10 install from HP OEM Recovery media. Downloaded network driver to USB stick on another PC, and transferred to new PC and try to install.

Installation takes a lot longer than usual, and eventually produces error 'No Intel adaptors found on this system'.

I've had this on multiple systems, including the 600 G2. What is strange is that it seems to always work eventually- I installed the chipset driver and BIOs update on machine no.1 and after a restart, the network functioned.

On machine no.2, the above didn't cause it to start working.

I've reinstalled Windows on hundreds of computers and I've always just installed the network driver and then been on my merry way. Never had issue on 600 G1, just the G2 and G3.

Does anyone have any suggestions- am I being silly?

Comment: In my experience OEM recovery disks are a cover-all for a range of machines, and dont cater for minor hardware updates, and online driver listings can be out of date. Manufacturers often swap controller chips with no notice.
Are you SURE its the right driver you downloaded?? You need to check EXACTLY what network controller is onboard, Presumably it's on the Motherboard not a discreet card. I tend to use "Unknown Device Identifier"

Comment: Hi,It's a 'current' model of machine, and driver is from the manufacturer website- and it's up-to-date. There are also no other options for Ethernet drivers- this is the only one listed. Booting the machine with factory install of windows shows that it is the correct model in device manager.

Comment: Unfortunately currency and "there are no other options" mean sod-all in the real world - you need to be 100% sure that the driver pack is suitable for the exact controller chip in use. 
source: many many years in IT.

Comment: As stated, the driver downloaded matched the model number for that already preinstalled on the system. It seems to have resolved by updating the Intel ME Firmware. HP Support also advised that exact .exe in a support conversation (going from serial number).

Answer (score 0):

Following an update of the Intel ME Firmware this now appears to work. Whether this is a coincidence or not, I'm not sure, but it's a strange issue- I've never had to install other items before network drives before.